# Sync GitHub Repositories into Azure DevOps

Tags: git, azure, github, azure-devops, clone

I have 2 Repositories in my GitHub Organization Account:
Say `Repo1` and `Repo2`. In order to bring these into `Azure DevOps`, I followed the below steps:

1. I signed into `Azure DevOps` and Created a new Project.
2. Under `Project Settings`, Created a new `GitHub Connection`.
3. Under `Repos`, Imported `Git Repository` using `GitHub Clone URL` and `PAT Authentication`.

With this, I'm able to see my `GitHub repositories` cloned into `Azure DevOps GIT`. But there is no sync between them.

If I create a new Branch of `Repo1` in `Azure DevOps GIT` then it's not reflecting in `GitHub`. Similary, If I create a new Branch of `Repo1` in `GitHub` then it's not reflecting in `Azure DevOps GIT`.

Is it the right way of Importing from `GitHub` to `Azure DevOps GIT`? Am I missing something here? Please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it the right way of Importing from GitHub to Azure DevOps GIT?

Yes, this is the correct way. Importing only creates a copy. It will not keep the two in sync automatically.

Comment: Is there any way of handling this sync?

Comment: @ShreekumarS There is always a way. The limiting factor is always how much time you have to spend on it. One possibility is to set up a repo on a machine you control where you can do a `git fetch` and `git push` each branch. But why, though?

Comment: Got your point. The problem is Some teams have access to `GitHub` and other teams have access to `Azure Git`.  As you said, for development activities, we can use `Azure Git` and for showcase purposes (to other teams), we can push the changes to `GitHub` periodically. Thanks!

Comment: @ShreekumarS Is there any reason you can't just give all your teams access to the repo all on a single platform?

Comment: Yeah. All teams are from different Organizations, and we have some limitations with respect to Access to all resources.